# URL errors / MAMP windows

Tags: php, oop, url, model-view-controller, mamp

My these codes are not matching kindly help me what i am doing wrong , i am following the instructor checked my codes 3 times but i think there is something still missing.

config.php file url defines

```
define('ROOT_PATH', '/');
define('ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost/oop');
```

i have 2 navbar options home and shares , 
when i click on home it says

> > This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect. Search Google for localhost oop
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

and url changed into localhost/oop

else if i enter localhost:8888 its working fine and opening the home page
and if i click on shares same error come and still if i write url like this

localhost:8888/shares  everything working fine but when i click on shares on navbar then url change into localhost:8888/oop/shares   and error

main.php where im calling these link and it not working

```
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>shares">Shares</a></li>
```

Thank you

Comment: change `define('ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost/oop');` to `define('ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost/');`

Comment: You could just use relative URLs.

Comment: still not working

Comment: add `/` after localhost. `define('ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost/');`

Answer (score -1):

Port is import point for computer communication when you don't type any port in browser and look for a url it sends request to port 80 of the server. While your server is listening at 8888 your server won't listens on port 80 and hence browser try to search and that make it a google search.

You have two options to handle that.

1. Start listening onPort 80 and it will work fine
2. Just add the port with your url
   `define('ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost/oop');` change it to `define('ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/oop');`

Comment: Where is your shares file?? inside oop or outside ??

Comment: inside oop , controllers folder

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it with changes and help from users here and the solution is

```
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL.'home'; ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL.'shares'; ?>">Shares</a></li>
```